# Invoking an applet from another applet

Tags: java, html, applet

I have a scenario wherein one applet has to trigger the invocation of another applet. Please suggest me how I go about it.

Sanjeev Gopinath V

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622377/inter-applet-communication/2622442#2622442

Answer (score 0):

Taken from this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/258955/Applets/java/call-one-applet-another) - Hope this will help you -

you can call another applet using

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(URL, "_blank")
```

where URL is the HTML page containing the second applet. That will open a new window.