# Java Applet to Applet communication with only one Instance

Tags: java, japplet

i´ve got to write a simple JApplet for homework and i´m kinda stuck. It´s pretty simple the applet has one JTextField and one JButton.

Now, if i open that Applet two times they are supposed to communicate(write in the TextField->click the Button and the text shows in the other TextField), but without something like Client-Server Communication. The two times i open the Applet, they have to be **the same Instance.**

I´m pretty much a noob when it comes to Applets, so i appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it have to be an applet?  There are some many restrictions on what an applet can do, you might find yourself butting heads with it...

Comment: You can also check out [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/iac.html) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622377/inter-applet-communication/) for ideas

Comment: Yes, my teacher won´t accept anything else.

Answer (score 0):

When in doubt, always check the Java tutorials from Oracle.
Here's a link to a tutorial for inter applet communication
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/iac.html