# How to access a volatile KeyListener ArrayList?

Tags: java

I am trying to create a GUI (using Applet) the user enters keyboard input (using KeyListner) and read the data from a different class.
The problem is that the ArrayList (which holds the data) always appears as empty

I have tried to make the ArrayList volatile, create a copy and to put the copy in a synchronized block.

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.List;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Listen extends Applet implements KeyListener {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static ArrayList<Integer> keysDown = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public void init() {
    this.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(!keysDown.contains(e.getKeyCode())) {
        keysDown.add(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
    }
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keysDown.remove(new Integer(e.getKeyCode()));
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public static ArrayList<Integer> getKeys() {
    ArrayList<Integer> keysDownCopy;
    synchronized (keysDown) {
        keysDownCopy = new ArrayList<Integer>(keysDown);
        System.out.println(keysDownCopy);
    }
    return keysDownCopy;
}
}
```

It is called from a different class:

```
public class Controler{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while(true) {
           Listen.getKeys();
       }
   }
}
```

The ArrayList supposed to show all of the IDs of the pressed keys but shown as just empty ( [] ).

Comment: You are running an applet and a regular java application, which run in distinct VMs, they can't access the state of each other.

Comment: @Arnaud so there is no way to get that values?

Comment: You may find a way to access it between two applets (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622377/inter-applet-communication/) . Also note that applet is an obsolete technology.

Comment: @Arnaud thank you! What should I use instead of Applet?

Comment: You may want to try JavaFX for graphical applications, but they are standalone applications, not embedded in web pages.

Comment: @Arnaud will do. Thank you!