# Singleton in Applets

Tags: java, applet, singleton

We have a Singleton which maintains current UI state of the applet. The problem is:

1. User opens applet page in browser, selects a value in drop down.
2. user browses another page in application which is pure HTML.
3. user comes back to applet page, UI state is intact i.e. the value he selected in drop down is there. This state of drop down comes from a Singleton, which saves applets UI state.
4. user again goes to a purely HTML page in application.
5. User comes back to applet page again, and this time the state is lost and reset to default layout (drop downs contains default value).

The reason I found is that, the Singleton which saves UI state is not able to persist its state when user goes back to applet second time. All static variables are reset to their default value.

I found that applets should be stateless as this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/applet/best_practices.html#state):

Which says:

> Values stored in the applet could persist between invocations, if the memory acquired by the class loader cache isn't needed for other purposes. But you can't depend on that behavior. In general, applets should be stateless. If persistent storage is needed, use browser cookies.

In this case, how can we create Singletons for Applets ? I can't save whole UI state in browser cookies.

Comment: there is really no effective way to achieve a singleton in an embedded applet. Otoh launch it free floating using JWS and the SingleInstanceService can be used to ensure a single instance.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
Would the instantiation of the applet in JWS be accessible to the JRE plugin in the browser?  If not how would an applet access the JWS objects?

Comment: @cp. Yes if it is embedded, no if it is free floating.  Why do you need a singleton?  Why do you need an applet?

Comment: @AndrewThompson
How does an applet in a page access a JWS object?  Are they the same JVM? Do you get an instance and call methods directly?  What has to be done to make sure they are the same JVM in the applet tag? Previously have done it with applet in two tabs and it worked "mostly well enough". The reason is we are accessing 3rd party hardware over USB w/JNI layer that up to now can only be accessed as applet.

Answer (score 1):

I see some options for this :

1. send a http request to the server to save the current state, use an ajax call, reference for the http call in a applet : [how to (simply) generate POST http request from java to do the file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314300/how-to-simply-generate-post-http-request-from-java-to-do-the-file-upload)
2. save the state using a cookie, here is the reference : [can java applets (not signed) create / read cookies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962823/can-java-applets-not-signed-create-read-cookies)
3. make calls to a javascript function to use Jstorage to save the state in the local storage of the browser, reference : http://www.jstorage.info/

The use of Jstorage is pretty simple take a look on this example that stores a counter called "contador"

```
<html><head>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jstorage.js"></script>
<script>
    function init() {
        var contador = $.jStorage.get("contador");
        $('#you').html('contador=' + contador);
        contador++;
        $.jStorage.set("contador", contador);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id="you"></div>
</body>
</html>
```